# How can I call shell_exec() from PHP webhook?

Tags: php, python, exec, webhooks, cgi-bin

I'm having a major issue and I can't find a solution. I currently have a PHP script that accepts a webhook (HTTP POST) as a trigger. Based on variables contained in the POST, an exec('python script') is supposed to run, and return some variables. It works fine when I run it from the command line it works fine, but when I try to trigger the script from any type of HTTP request, the exec() function does not run. Here is the section of code that is affected:

```
$command = shell_exec('python C:\\xampp\\cgi-bin\\SECpull.py');

$company_dump = print_r($command, TRUE);
$fp = fopen('retvals.txt', 'w');
fwrite($fp, $company_dump);
fclose($fp);
```

If it isn't possible to have an exec() function in a PHP script that is triggerd by an HTTP POST, then how should I go about this?

Comment: It's totally possible, and there's nothing wrong with your code (assuming that asterix is a typo). It's likely that the user running your web server doesn't have permission to run the command. You can test this from the command line by running your script as that user instead of the default. I don't know how to do it on windows, but on a unix system it'd be something like `sudo -u apache php myscript.php` (if `apache` runs your web server)

Comment: The asterisks were an attempt to highlight that line as the one to focus on in my script. I'll fix that to remove confusion.

Comment: So many things can go wrong here. It will be more usefull if you could post what the error is that you see. shell_exec is not a safe way of doing things. Why not a pure PHP solution or a pure python solution instead of mixing?

Comment: For a number of reasons but the main one is that I'm using one Python-only library and one PHP-only library. I could forego the PHP script, but the problem there is receiving the webhooks (POSTs mainly). Frankly, I don't fully understand how to create an endpoint to send requests to using python. In PHP it is simple. I just send the request to the URL of the script. With Python it isn't so easy because everything is in the cgi-bin. I am still learning, so go easy on me, but an explanation of how to create a python endpoint would solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem**

As [Robbie Averill](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2812842/robbie-averill) mentioned, most probably you have a permission issue and you can fix it by adding additional permissions to user that is used to run the web server. However, I think it is not a good style to mix [php](/questions/tagged/php) with [python](/questions/tagged/python), and if you cannot re-write `SECpull.py` to [php](/questions/tagged/php), then better do everything in [python](/questions/tagged/python).

I suggest you to use [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) for that.

**Sample**

```
# server.py
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

# Setup custom route here
@app.route("/") 
def index():
    # Add SECpull.py logic here.
    return "Welcome To Python Server!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

**Setup**

```
$ pip install Flask
$ python server.py

* Running on http://localhost:5000/
```